# Pandas in PyCharm: Where does it display the boxplot?

Tags: pandas, pycharm, boxplot, python-3.7

I am making a python script using the PyCharm IDE, and the idea is to display descriptive statistics and a box plot for each group in a DataFrame. The statistics displays, but the boxplot is nowhere to be seen...

I have tried Googling an answer, but it does not seem this question have been answered before.

```py
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib as plt

    (...)

    for name, group in grouped:
        if len(group) > 3:
            print("\n\nNAME: {}".format(name))
            print("GROUP: {}".format(group))
            print("DESCRIPTIVE STATISTICS 
{}".format(group.distance2.describe()))
            print(group.distance2.plot.box())
            group.distance2.plot.box()
```

I do not get any error messages, the code runs and completes, but I do not know where the boxplot is supposed to display.

Comment: If i use print, the code outputs this:

AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.77)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the code as it is does not create a matplotlib figure object.  Try creating a test data object for group.distance2, then create a matplotlib boxplot object.  I am assuming you are using the matplotlib library.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for name, group in grouped:
    if len(group) > 3:
        data = group.distance2
        # create a matplotlib figure object
        fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 1)
        # basic plot
        axs[0, 0].boxplot(data)
        axs[0, 0].set_title('basic plot of group.distance2')
        plt.show()
```

It that works, you can try putting several group data into one figure (axes).  Here is more information:  https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/statistics/boxplot_demo.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not clarify that I am using pandas, which in turn is using matplotlib.I got the following error when running your code: 
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 1)
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'subplots'

Comment: In an earlier version of the script, it displayed the plot, but not now...

Comment: You were correct, I just used the import matplotlib as plt, and not import matplotlib.pyplot as plt. For some reason I also tried to call .show() from the dataframe, and not just type plt.show()

Comment: Hi Centurion, Glad that worked! :-)
Could you vote my answer up and accept this answer as having solved your problem?  I'm new to StackOverflow, so don't have many votes yet. :-)

Comment: Of course :) I accepted your answer and voted up. Unfortunately, since I am new as well, the score will not display publicly I am told...

Comment: Thank you!!!  I know it sucks being new. :-(  I think you will get there though, just keep posting.  Cheers!  Jennifer